# CCS: MPU6050 Sensorlib

Tags: texas-instruments, code-composer, cmsis

I'm Using TM4C123G board and I have followed the example given in the 'SW-TM4C-SENSORLIB-UG-1.1.pdf' for interfacing MPU6050, But I'm facing trouble in generating the I2C communication. Is that example is enough or should I extra line for communication. If yes then can you please mention the changes that I have to make.

Answer (score 0):

I think the example should work like it is, but you have to provide external PullUp Resistors to your I2C Lines.

Can you run through the Code with the Debugger?